# Generic fwrite function

Tags: c++, google-nativeclient

I am using Google Native client which requires background thread to manage IO operations. I am writing fwrite now but I am having a trouble passing data to the function and validating the data.

here is the case, below is how I want to pass the data of course I am not restricted to `char[]` I want to it to work for any data type as long as `fwrite` accept that type

```
pp::VarDictionary fileOp;
    pp::VarArray args;
    char buffer[] = { 'x' , 'y' , 'z' };
    args.Set(0, buffer); //name of buffer I want to pass
    args.Set(1, 1); //size of elements
    args.Set(2,sizeof(buffer));//the size of buffer
    args.Set(3, outfile); //the output file
    fileOp.Set("args", args);
    fileOp.Set("cmd", "fwrite");
    queue_file_.push(fileOp);
```

For the function that will handle the operation this is what I have

```
int EncoderInstance::HandleFwrite(pp::VarArray params, std::string* error) {

    if (params.GetLength() != 3) {
        Logger::Log("Invalid number of arguments");
        return 0;
    }


    outfile = fwrite(params.Get(0), sizeof(char), sizeof(params.Get(0)), outfile);

    if (!outfile) {

        *error = "fopen returned a NULL FILE*";
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

My questions are the following

1. How can I make validation to all the inputs so no exceptions are raised? For `fopen` I checked if it has two parameters and both of them are strings `filename` and `mode` for `fwrite` I am confused what should I do
2. What is the best way to pass parameters without consuming the memory? this is a video encoder so I do not want the validation and writing to take long.
3. Do I have to cast all of inputs or is there a generic way to do it?